# Can not create or view AppsFolders

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell

How do i create a new folder folder for my apps.
Have installed *GNOME App Folders Manager v0.3.1*, but the created folders does not come in to view.

I had read that this function is native supported in Gnome 3.38.
I have the preinstalled Utilities folder, but create new ones and how bring others them in to view?
I installed the **minimum install**, could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

OK the answer is to drop an app on top of an other app :-)

[Youtube - News in 20.04](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9u5B0njRgOw)